# Is there a command to got to WORDIR of a recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

So while working on a couple of recipes, sometimes I need to go to the WORKDIR of a recipe to make sure if it is doing what is supposed to. I know there is :

```
bitbake myrecipe -c devshell
```

but this blocks bitbake and while the new shell is running , i can't test or experiment on other recipes.

is there a command to simply `cd` to the WORKDIR of a recipe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cd `bitbake myrecipe -e | grep ^WORKDIR= | cut -d '"' -f 2`

bitbake myrecipe -e  shows you the variables set in that recipe context, the rest of the shell extracts the directory.

Comment: thanks, for completion this is the full command with the cd  : ```cd $(bitbake viwiproxy -e | grep ^WORKDIR= | cut -d '"' -f 2)```